# How to call a method in parent component from child component in angular 4 within a promise?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call a method in the parent component from the child component in angular 4 using .emit();

app.component.html

```
<parent-component (loadMoreData)="loadData()"></parent-component>
```

Parent Component html:

```
<div>
  <child-component [dataList]="dataList"></child-component>
</div>
```

Parent Component.ts

```
public dataList : Array<any>;

constructor() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  loadData(){
    //const options = this.getOptions();
    this.appServices.getDataList().subscribe((response) => {
      const respJson = response;
      this.dataList = respJson;
      console.log(this.assayDataList);
    });
  }
```

Child component.ts

```
@Output() loadMoreData : EventEmitter<boolean>;

public getRowData():Promise<any[]>{
    var self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
      self.loadMoreData.emit(true);
      resolve(this.assayTableData);
    })
  }
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Child component you should initialize the EventEmitter.

```
@Output() loadMoreData : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);
```